# Compounding a gamma distribution with another distribution to yield a gamma

Tags: gamma-distribution, compound-distributions

I have a gamma distributed random variable $X$, with its mean $\mu$ distributed as some other function
$$
X \sim \text{Gamma}(\mu,k)\\
\mu \sim P(\theta)
$$

What is the distribution $P(\theta)$ such that when I marginalize out $\mu$, $X$ is still distributed as a gamma distribution, perhaps with updated parameters?

$$
p(x|k,\theta)=\int_0^{\infty} d\mu\, p(x|\mu,k)p(\mu|\theta)
$$
i.e. $p(x|k,\theta)=\frac{x^{\kappa-1}e^{- x\kappa/\phi}}{(\phi/\kappa)^{\kappa}\Gamma(\kappa)}$ where $\phi,\kappa$ are functions of $k,\theta$

Comment: You might require the self study tag.

Comment: Hint: the sum of Gamma distributions (with a common scale parameter) is a Gamma distribution.